# Win 2003 Shared Folder

Tags: windows-server-2003, file-sharing, session, limitations

We have shared one folder on win2003 server and allowed everyone to access it but only 8-9 users are allowed to map drive the shared folder. The next is connected once I disconnect the one of the sessions.

Pls advise.

Answer (score 0):

It should be one of the following:

- (Less Likely) Your share folder properties are limiting access to a specific number, make sure that the setting is set to "Unlimited".
- (More Likely) Your server CALs are less than 8-9, you need to add more CALs to allow more users to connect to the server.